# vertically align multi-line text within a floated div

Tags: css, vertical-alignment

I have been playing around with different methods to vertically align multi lined text.  Basically I have something like what is in this fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/xPxwn/

```
<div class = "box">  <h2>multiline text goes here</h2> 
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.box
    {

width:100px;  
height:40px;
    border:1px solid;
    background:blue;
    color:yellow;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    margin:5px;
    text-align:center;
    font : 50% "Trebuchet MS", verdana, arial, tahoma, sans-serif;
    float:left;
    }
```

I need the text to be vertically aligned within the box but I am failing to come up with a solution.  Any ideas?

Thanks in advance
Chris

Answer (score 1):

If you don't need to float the box and can rework your layout a bit you can try this out. `display:table-cell` and `vertical-align:middle` added to `.box` and `float:left` removed.

```
 .box
    {
    display:table-cell;
    vertical-align:middle;
    width:100px;  
    height:40px;
    border:1px solid;
    background:blue;
    color:yellow;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    padding:0;margin:0;    
    text-align:center;
    font : 50% "Trebuchet MS", verdana, arial, tahoma, sans-serif;
    }        
.box>h2{padding:0;margin:0;}
```

Comment: Thanks, but I do need to float the box because I have many boxes positioned with float.

Comment: @user1658170 What does that have to do with floating the `.box` element?